# Is there a way in pandas to count the number of duplicates across years?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Not exactly sure how to ask the question but I can show a clear before and after that would help.

My data looks like this:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'userID': [1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3], 
                        'Year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022]})
temp_df
```

| userID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2020 |
| 4 | 2021 |
| 3 | 2021 |
| 4 | 2022 |
| 3 | 2022 |

I want to create a rolling count of userIDs so I can see how many userIDs are still around and for how long.
So it should end up being something like this:

| Year | Number of ids from last year | Number of ids from 2 years ago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022 | 2 | 1 |

and so on and so forth.

I don't know how to go about solving this so I thought it better to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets to keep track of the seen IDs:

```
s = temp_df.groupby('Year')['userID'].agg(set)

N = 2
df = (pd.DataFrame({f'n-{i}': [len(a&b) for a,b in zip(s, s.shift(i, fill_value=set()))]
                    for i in range(1, N+1)}, index=s.index)
        .reset_index()
      )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Year  n-1  n-2
0  2020    0    0
1  2021    1    0
2  2022    2    1
```

Comment: Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding earlier but this answer is perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: @YisroelLen thanks for the feedback, you might consider accepting the answer if this worked well for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not ranked high enough to do that :(